# Android gps provider and gps icon

Tags: android, gps, location

Today when i was trying my code, a few doubtful thing appeared in my mind about gps provider, gps hardware, gps icon and fine location permission.

I observed my code and gps icon on Samsung galaxy s3, Htc one m8. And gps is **disabled**

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 0, this, Looper.myLooper());
...
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mListenerRef.get().onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Galaxy s3 - Gps icon didn't appear, it didn't fire onLocationChanged method. (Thats okay)

Htc one m8 - Gps icon **appeared, blinking, and fired** onLocationChanged (But how ?)

At this moment questions pops up

- Does ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission give the app override gps status on some devices?
- So, could the app receive location even gps disabled ?

And then i enabled gps on galaxy s3

(First 2 minutes) Gps icon appeared(**but not blinking**), fired onLocationChanged method (But how ?)

(After 2 minutes) Gps icon appeared(**blinking**), fired onLocationChanged method

Again questions pops up

- What does gps icon blinking mean ? any extracanonical meaning  ?
- Does the blinking mean gps hardware trying first fix ?
- Or blinking means the provider firing onLocationChanged method ?

Answer (score 2):

**What does gps icon blinking mean?**

-> Well I hope u r aware that GPS provider dosen't work under roof. So it is completely impossible to get Location update from GPS provider under roof. In such situation if user enables the GPS then the GPS blinking icon appears notifying to user that it is searching for GPS.

-> Once it finds the GPS the icon dosen't blink anymore and u'll get location updates from GPS provider.

-> A still GPS icon means Android system is ready to send location updates from GPS provider.

---

**Htc one m8 - Gps icon appeared, blinking, and fired onLocationChanged (But how ?)**

-> It sounds weird getting location updates without enabling it. I'm not sure how u confirmd that u got the Location update.

-> I'll recommend u to check if GPS provider is enabled and then request for location update.

Answer (score 1):

Fine_location permission will enable user to have update from gps, wifi, network. So if gps is unavailable still onlocationChange() can be fired because a recent location may have been fetched via wifi/network.

(quote from the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.
)

How your phone showed gps icon without gps being enabled, I doubt it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With HTC One (M7) the APP has permission to use the GPS and that makes 'GPS' fair game - ('GPS' = 'GPS Spoofer', AGPS [if permitted], an APP that uses WiFi and GPS [thus position is almost always immediately available], and, of course, the Phone's real Hardware GPS / GLONASS / Galileo / etc.).

The HTC UI has an Icon for the Application that uses the GPS (whatever the Phone thinks the Provider IS, a few APPs do check Provider; they don't accept spoofed Locations, EG: Most Subscription APPs, Google Play Store, abrev. GPS;) ).

A second Icon appears for the Hardware GPS. It flashes while it waits for enough Satellites. Indoors, without WiFi, with AGPS, I can get a lock in less than 1/2 min.

You probably want to check the Error when you get your LC Message, since if you're over 100 M off you don't *really* know where you are and probably don't have a valid position; pending calculations from one more (weak) Satellite may be enough to get you below 50 M Error, at which point you should start accepting the Location as valid (your APP might want to record Error with Coordinates, then Locations can be displayed with a circle representing the uncertainty).

When Developing you want to be certain to buy the most popular Phone (so you have real Hardware to test on, and support the greatest number of Customers), and to buy a FEW Phones with the Hardware that you want your Android APPs to control - in your case buy Phones with *different* GPS Hardware, for others they may need to buy a few Phones with different Camera Hardware (or WiFi Chip, etc.).

Between the Cell Phone Mfgs version of Android, their UI, and the manner in which their GPS Hardware operates (along with other APPs you have installed, like a Spoofer) you have a LOT of variables that your Program must juggle and many situations (Error Returns) that it must allow for to operate identically on as many Devices as possible.